# Why does ulimits get reset after changing /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, localhost

This is a Fedora 25 system.
I had to update the system name to `node-1` When I did this by updating the `/etc/hosts` file, my `/etc/security/limits.conf` file was also reset. Why does this happen?
After that I am not able to set my ulimits for the same user. though the once for `root` are fine.

Below is the excerpt from the /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   node-1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         node-1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.0.2.15   node-1
```

Below is the changes I made to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
rranjan        soft    nofile          65536
rranjan        hard    nofile          65536
rranjan        soft    memlock         unlimited
rranjan        hard    memlock         unlimited
rranjan        soft    as              unlimited
rranjan        hard    as              unlimited
rranjan        soft    nproc           2048
rranjan        hard    nproc           2048

root           soft    nofile          65536
root           hard    nofile          65536
root           soft    memlock         unlimited
root           hard    memlock         unlimited
root           soft    as              unlimited
root           hard    as              unlimited
root           soft    nproc           2048
root           hard    nproc           2048
```

How do i get the ulimits working again? Or is it something wrong that I have done?

Comment: It would help if we knew what dist you are using.

Comment: Updated it. Its a Fedora 25 system.